# Fields not showing up after deployment

Tags: deployment

I successfully deployed a large amount of fields into production, and none of them appear on the object. I went to edit layout, and none of them appear as options. If this a matter of time, or is there some setting I need to fix to make them available? I apologize if this is too general of a question, I will do my best to add details as needed to narrow down the issue...

Comment: Does the status say Validate: Succeeded  (or) Deploy: Succeeded in the source org?

Comment: They're deployed

Comment: That was my only guess that you validated and never deployed the component. Do you see the custom fields as part of your change set under the component section in your target org?

Comment: If you navigate to the field in the Setup menu, are the fields actually listed?

Comment: Indeed I do. It's strange, I checked the object again and when I go to make a new one, some of the fields are now options, but not all that were included in the change set. Perhaps it's something that has to do with time. I can continue other things and check it in a few hours. Strange, isn't it? I always thought they show up once deployed...

Comment: That comment was in response to them being in the target org change set -- I have not checked the setup menu yet

Comment: You have to modify profiles and permission sets to be able to view/edit, even SysAdmin. By doing custom fields/object deployment with Change Sets, always include Profiles and Permission Sets (the one you configured in sandbox)

Comment: I never specified any permission sets except for when making the fields, gave access to all profiles -- when I went into the permission sets in a new change component to take a look, I don't recognize any of them. I know I've never specified anything explicitly with any of them. How do I know what permission sets to include for these fields?

Comment: i ran into something like this yesterday, and it was just setting up FLS on Custom fields. I'm sure you must have checked it, but no harm in double checking.

Comment: Deploy all the related Page Layouts at time of deployment.